# How to make the condition to be a Eventhandler Control.click event?

Tags: c#, forms, if-statement, event-handling

Basically what I am trying to do is, creating a new method that will have an event handler button click event condition within it.enter code here

```
 //when this event is active the only should then should run what inside the {}
if(buttonEvents_Click(object sender, EventArgs e))
{enter code here`
//Happening something
}
```

what I already tried withing(buttonEvents.click) get the error "the event control.click can only appear on the left side =+ or -+".

Answer (score 0):

You should have your event handler method like you always do:

```
buttonEvents_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(condition){ //you need your condition checker inside the method
    //... coder here
   }
}
```

now for any control that you want to add this handler you can sompliy do:

```
myButton.Click += buttonEvents_Click;
```

Alternatively you can do this like:

```
myButton.Click += (s, e) => 
{
      //which s is the sender and e is the EventArgs
      //code here
};
```

Comment: by if(myButton.Click += buttonEvents_Click) i am getting : "cannot implicitly convert void to bool" by alternative if(myButton.Click += (sender, e) => "get the same error"

Comment: but there is no `if` in my code, what do you need if for?

Comment: There is a form and that form buttons on it, each button brings to front different User-Controls and I want when that eventbutton is clicked and the admin put the mouse over the button to make a panel visible.
To do that i planed to create a new methode where the condition is if(that eventbutton.clicked).

And by the  private void buttonEvents_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e) {here to call that method}, hope that i am more understanble now

Comment: you need that if inside the handler: `buttonEvents_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(condition) {  code here  }
}` the event triggers anyway, but does the job if condition is met, you cannot do it other way, condition in `if` should only be a boolean value, event handler is not a boolean